# How do I tell if a form is in help mode?

Tags: winforms, delphi

There's a certain control which I don't have the source to (Steema TTree) it doesn't send a help message when help is requested through the form. (clicking the ? near the X on the dialog, then clicking the TTree)

I can just call help directly on the form and pass in my own helpmessage, but I don't know whether the form is in help mode.

The form's cursor is acutally 0 even when it has a ? next to it... That I find odd.

Anyway, I know I'm hacking my way through this, but I don't care.  All I want to know is if there is a way to tell whether the user is requesting help and currently has a ? next to their cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Torry](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1225) helped

```
 procedure wmNCLButtonDown(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDown); message WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN;
 procedure wmNCLButtonUp(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonUp); message WM_NCLBUTTONUP;
```

I overrode those functions to set a global variable

```
 fHelpMode : Boolean
```

to true when

```
 if Msg.HitTest = HTHELP then
      fHelpMode := true;
```

That allowed me to know when if the user was requesting help and I could override a mouse event on the TTree to do my help pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

> The form's cursor is acutally 0 even
>   when it has a ? next to it... That I
>   find odd.

That's because that is your forms cursor

Try Screen.Cursor that should be the active one.

Comment: procedure TForm.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar(format('%d',[ord(Cursor)])));
  OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar(format('%d',[ord(Screen.Cursor)])));
end;

Output is 0 for both.  
Also, the ? disappears when I drag it off the dialog. Though you're probably right, something's cursor is set to ?